# How to access value inside this array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

I have an array like this:

[image]

I need to access the `value` which is set to **876**.

The code behind this array goes here:

```
       try {
            $totalTck = $TransactionBuilder->triggerSmartContract(
                (array)$abi,
                $contractH,
                $function,
                $params,
                $feeLimit,
                $addressH,
                $callValue = 0,
                $bandwidthLimit = 0);

                dd($totalTck);
        } catch (\IEXBase\TronAPI\Exception\TronException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

How can I get the `value` from this array?

Comment: if it contain multiple then better to use loop or else $totalTck[0]['value']['value']

Comment: @JohnLobo `Cannot use object of type phpseclib\Math\BigInteger as array`

Comment: @can you print_r instead of dd so  ican see entire result

Comment: @JohnLobo `Array ( [0] => phpseclib\Math\BigInteger Object ( [value] => 0x036c [engine] => gmp ) )`

Comment: $totalTck[0]->value

Comment: @JohnLobo Thank u, plz add that as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its Object  inside array.So you should access as arrow

```
$totalTck[0]->value
```